# How to get the primary email associated with the kindle fire account?

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I am integrating a in app purchase logic using the Amazon 'in app purchasing' API and I want to determine the amazon store email without being connected to the internet.

How to get the primary email associated with the kindle account (the one used by the App-Shop, not the one of the email app) ?

The AccountManager gives me only the email attached to my email client.

Is it possible to get it with the "Login with Amazon API" without using the login service ?

Thank you